# What is the effect of spreading a workout over a day?

Tags: workout-routines, strength

Suppose I have a gym routine that I want to fulfil, with the goal of strengthening a particular set of muscles. (I don't care about increasing bulk or definition at all).

The current plan is gym sessions that are 3 sets of 10 reps on each of a couple of excercises that work those muscles. Done in an ABC_ABC_ABC pattern. The sessions take me ~30-45 minutes and get me moderately sweaty, and I'm gradually increasing the load on all the excercises.

Currently my biggest problem is actually DOING the session - I put them off and skip them :(

One way that I think would make it easier for me to actually do them would be to split the excercise up. Say first thing in the morning I do just the first set, or the first block of set, then a few hours later I do another set/block, then I do my last set/block at the end of the day.

I think that I will be more likely to succesfully DO that routine.

**What would be the effect of that change? Does doing the excercises all together make a difference? Or does it not matter when I do stuff as long as I do the whole routine by the end of the day?**

---

*Context which may or may not be relevant?*

*I am specifically trying to fully recover an on-going hamstring injury. I have twice recovered to the point where I had no pain or range issues, including being able to train and sprint fully, and then during the first or second 100% pace match have re-pulled the hamstring.*

*Specific excerices are a combination of Double leg RDLs (X kg), Double-leg Good Mornings (X kg), Single-leg RDLs (~60% of X kg), Side leg raises, Side planks.*

*I have a small work gym, hence it is plausible to just walk in, do a set and walk back out*

Comment: I wonder if you do a warm up/cool down thing every time or if those are exercises where you don't have to warm up for

Answer (score 2):

when working out everything help, especially with injury its best to take your time so that you don't form another injury. if your missing these exercises because you feel pain or became uncomfortable then all good. if your missing just because you don't feel like it, get some pre workout drink i recommend (crack3d u4x) . these workouts are designed to tire your muscles out so they grow. so you will get better results doing your entire workout at once.